# How can I create an SPF record on my 1and1.com hosted domain?

Tags: dns, email, google-workspace

Emails from my domain (hosted at 1and1, and using Google Apps Premier edition) have sporadically been going to recipients' spam folders lately.  I did some research, tested, and found out that I do not have an SPF record for my domain.  According to [this](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=178723) Google Support page, I need to create one.  Following the steps on that page is easy, until I get to #3:

> Create a TXT record containing this text: v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all

I see no way to create a "TXT record".  Here is a screenshot of the admin panel:

[image: dns settings]

Comment: I'm not sure how I feel about host-specific configuration questions. Asked question on Meta to see how folks feel about this:  http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88/questions-about-technical-setup-at-specific-hosts

Comment: 1and1 have now added support for TXT records:

http://help.1and1.co.uk/domains-c40986/manage-domains-c79879/dns-c43146/add-or-remove-txt-records-a792794.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not familiar with 1and1 DNS hosting, but if they won't let you create a `txt` record then you will need to switch your DNS hosting to someone who does.

From a quick google it looks like 1and1 won't let you do this*

From the horses mouth:

> As of Aug, 7 2007 - "Yes, we do understand what an SPF record is.
>   Unfortunately we do not support in on
>   our hosting plans. We apologize for
>   any inconvenience."

I've had great milage out of http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/ (as I need a commercial SLA) but there are "free" providers out there too.

<sub>*References:</sub>

1. http://osdir.com/ml/mail.spam.spf.help/2004-12/msg00174.html
2. http://www.1and1faq.com/forums/showthread.php?t=951
3. http://www.kitterman.com/spf/txt.html

Comment: http://www.dnspark.com/ is pretty decent too; handles all my employer's DNS stuff, very reliable.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread, but the problem with 1and1 not allowing SPF records still exists, so I wanted to share my solution to the problem. 1and1 will allow you to use an external DNS server, and we chose GoDaddy.com Premium DNS for only $36/year. It's easy to set up the records (with a little help from tech support -- the configuration is called an Off-Site domain, and you do not have to transfer your domains to GoDaddy), and the records are fully customizable, including multiple CNAME records and SPF. Good luck!

And to 1and1: what are you thinking? SPF became a recommended protocol in October 2004. Yes, that's right, over 8 years ago! You're just lucky that I was able to find a cheap external DNS service or I would have had to switch to another ISP because the spam problem was crippling our business. Wake up!

Comment: It looks like there is also a free option under GoDaddy.

Comment: 1and1 supports it meanwhile. Nevertheless I'd never recommend 1and1.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is looking for HOW TO CREATE AN SPF, then look here at  [Microsoft's very handy wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/safety/content/technologies/senderid/wizard/)...!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com)

On the My Websites page click on the Cog icon for the relevant site.  Then click on `DNS Settings`

Once on this page you can add various records [image].

In this case create a `TXT` record, enter your domain, and then `v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all`